# HtmlUnitDriver not getting page properly

Tags: selenium, webdriver, htmlunit, htmlunit-driver

I'm a newbie at this, basically I'm trying to use the HtmlUnitDriver,
this is my code:

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

But the page source I got is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
  <head/>
  <body/>
</html>
```

I have tried to to new HtmlUnitDriver(true) but it's still not loading google
I have already add the selenium server stand alone to the class path.
Am I doing anything wrong?
Thank you

P.S: Im using selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar and jre 1.7

Comment: Can't reproduce. I've just tested this exact code with Selenium 2.24.1 and got the whole page.

Comment: Im using selenium-server-standalone-2.24.1.jar and jre 1.7. So did I setup the project wrong or anything?

Comment: I have selenium-java which is a subset of selenium-server-standalone... I really have no idea what could possible be wrong. Are you behind a proxy? Does it work in any other WebDriver?

Comment: yeah everything else works such as IE driver and Firefox driver, and I'm not sure about the proxy

Comment: Okay, last shot. Try cleaning your classpath, delete all dependencies and re-download them again (Are you using Maven, Ivy, or anything similar? You might want to!). It _could_ be some [JAR-hell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JAR_hell)-related problem where some dependencies fight with each other.

Comment: I just tried that and still have the same problem. I also deleted the JRE library and added it back again. And Im not using Mavan or Ivy or anything. I only created a plain project from Eclipse

Comment: Yeah. I'm out. We'll see whether someone can confirm this / propose a solution. In the meantime, try it on another computer.

Answer (score 2):

HtmlUnitDriver defaults to having javaScript disabled
google.com relies heavily on javascript.
try using `driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true)`

```
WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true)
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is definitely due to proxy missing while starting htmlunitdriver. You will have to provide proxy details