# Get full source code of a webpage using htmlunitdriver

Tags: java

I Use this code for to print the page source.

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
driver.setJavascriptEnabled(true);

driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/");

String source=driver.getPageSource();
System.out.println(source);
```

But it is returning me only this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html>
<head/>
<body/>
</html>
```

Why is this happenning..?
How can i get the full source code..?
Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get a web page's source code from Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8616781/how-to-get-a-web-pages-source-code-from-java)

Comment: Have you tried searching this page.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11248300/htmlunitdriver-not-getting-page-properly